# Default aggregation in Tableau (SUM)

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation

Every time I load my data in Tableau's worksheets and put the number vaule into a column or row, it always enters it as a SUM aggregation by default and I cant turn it off,
any ideas?

Thanks

Can't find the answer on Tableau's website

Comment: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_aggregation.htm#:~:text=To%20change%20the%20default%20aggregation,only%20with%20relational%20data%20sources.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but is there a reason why its defaulted to SUM everytime I load a number value?

Comment: No reason that I know of other than that's how the Tableau programmers set it up. They had to choose something as the default, SUM was at the top of the list.